# jQuery selector for first row of inline-block divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some divs with display: inline-block; and I have to select first row of divs and set them for example different border color and I need to do it in javaScript (jQuery).

Here is my example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8193xgfn/5/)

HTML :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">item 1</div>
    <div class="item">item 2</div>
    <div class="item">item 3</div>
    <div class="item">item 4</div>
    <div class="item">item 5</div>
    <div class="item">item 6</div>
    <div class="item">item 7</div>
    <div class="item">item 8</div>
    <div class="item">item 9</div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 10px;
}

.item {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Is there a way how to do it?

Comment: Use table it will be easier than inline block

Comment: @SheraliTurdiyev: OP wants to target all elements displayed on the first line, which is not possible with CSS only. Your selector only gets first element...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to check what elements are in the first row, and mark those. A way to do this would be [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y539az05/)

This code makes the assumption that the first element is first in a row (which is always true), and checks which elements have the same offset top, it then applies a borderColor change to them

```
var top;
$('.container .item').each(function(i){
    var thistop = $(this).offset().top;
    if (i==0){
        top = thistop;
    }
    if (top==thistop){
        $(this).css({borderColor:"purple"});   
    }
});
```

Note that in a real life application you'd use a event handler on window resize to run this again on window resize.

I made a separate fiddle to do the event handler version. This requires wrapping above code in a function, and changing the functionality a bit to add/remove classes instead of just adding css (since adding and manually removing css get's messy). Fiddle can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wmyxtg5o/).

So instead of adding css, it adds/removes a class

```
markrow = function(){
        $('.container .item').each(function(i){
        ...
        if (top==thistop){
            $(this).addClass('special');
        }else{
            $(this).removeClass('special');
        }
    });
}
markrow();
$(window).on('resize',markrow);
```

With special being a css class that changes the border color

```
.special {
    border-color:purple;
}
```

Comment: that is first column not first row

Comment: Whoops, true! works the exact same way when we replace offset().left with .top though, il change it

Comment: Once fixed, this will probably be the best generic  answer to the OP's question

Comment: @LaurentS. i think so i tried it it works all he have to do is fix the fiddle

Comment: @Pekka that should fix it :)

Comment: @DrunkWolf great answer

Comment: I think it would be even better if the fiddle included the "window resize" event.

Comment: @LaurentS added fiddle with resize event

Answer (score 0):

You may use vanilla CSS Selector for this in jquery.
Assuming that you have a grid of 3 X 3.

```js
$( ".container .item:nth-child(3n + 1)" ).css( "border-color","black" );
```

Comment: In a responsive site, it is impossible to say only with CSS which elements are on the first row... OP is most probably looking for a generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.item').eq(0).addClass('special-border');

.special-border {
    border-color: #00f;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8193xgfn/9/

Answer (score 0):

you can get the width of your container which has a css-style named "container" by $(".container").width,

and then you can calculate how many divs can be put in the first row,and put it in a variable like firstrow_divNums.

now use $(".calculate").children() to get the child-divs,

finally use "for" loop from $(".calculate").children().eq(0) to $(".calculate").children().eq(firstrow_divNums) ,

and now you can do what you want  like adding css-style to any elements.