# jQuery selector for the higher inline-block div into its container's row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of divs inside a container.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">item 1</div>
    <div class="item">item 2 some text some text some text</div>
    <div class="item">item 3</div>
    <div class="item">item 4</div>
    <div class="item">item 5 some text/div>
    <div class="item">item 6</div>
    <div class="item">item 7 some text some text some text some text some text some text</div>
    <div class="item">item 8 some text</div>
    <div class="item">item 9</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 10px;
}

.item {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 120px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

In a such situation the result is that "items" have different heights, related to the text inside each one.

I would change the behavior of the "items" divs so that the higher "item" div of the ROW passes it's height to the other divs, but only those in the same row.

So each row's "item" must have the height of its row' higher element.

Obviously if I change the size of the viewport, the order of the rows changes, changing the arrangement.

Jquery or javascript, please.

Comment: *Need jquery or javascript, please.* .... what have you tried ?

Comment: I tried in jquery. The most similar solution I have found looking around is there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32473030/jquery-selector-for-first-row-of-inline-block-divs

Comment: @MatteoCorona Why not verify each height div and get the higher?

Comment: @MarcosSedrez I used this solution but it don't like it. The divs with little text results "empty" whe you look at them. The solution of Muhammad Usman is a good compromise between simmetry and balance, for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need JavaScript or jQuery. Use css3 [`flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 120px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">item 1</div>
    <div class="item">item 2 some text some text some text</div>
    <div class="item">item 3</div>
    <div class="item">item 4</div>
    <div class="item">item 5 some text</div>
    <div class="item">item 6</div>
    <div class="item">item 7 some text some text some text some text some text some text</div>
    <div class="item">item 8 some text</div>
    <div class="item">item 9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what about the jquery solution? Any suggestions please?

Comment: @MatteoCorona Sorry, I've not any such plugin in my knowledge.